# line fading while hovering on synchronized chart in highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I am having a synchronized highchart with two different containers. I have used a script to synchronize the charts. Synchronization works perfectly. My first chart is having 3 lines and second chart is having only 1 line.

> When I hover the first chart, the third line fading out. When I
>   disable the script for synchronisation it works fine.

This is my script for synchronisation.

```
$('#container, #container2').bind('mousemove touchmove touchstart', function(e) {
        var chart,
        points,
        i,
        secSeriesIndex = 1;

        for (i = 0; i < Highcharts.charts.length; i++) {
            chart = Highcharts.charts[i];
            e = chart.pointer.normalize(e); // Find coordinates within the chart
            points = [chart.series[0].searchPoint(e, true), chart.series[1].searchPoint(e, true)]; // Get the hovered point

            if (points[0] && points[1]) {
                if (!points[0].series.visible) {
                    points.shift();
                    secSeriesIndex = 0;
                }
                if (!points[secSeriesIndex].series.visible) {
                    points.splice(secSeriesIndex,1);
                }
                if (points.length) {
                    chart.tooltip.refresh(points); // Show the tooltip
                    chart.xAxis[0].drawCrosshair(e, points[0]); // Show the crosshair
                }
            }
        }
  });
```

[This is the jsfiddle link for the same.](https://jsfiddle.net/hakkim/fdqxhg67/3)

Can any one please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add all of the hovered points to the `points` array, not only the first two:

```
for (i = 0; i < Highcharts.charts.length; i++) {
    chart = Highcharts.charts[i];
    e = chart.pointer.normalize(e); // Find coordinates within the chart    
    points = [];

    chart.series.forEach(function(s) {
        points.push(s.searchPoint(e, true));
    });

    ...
}
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/goxm5q3e/

Comment: Do you have any idea how to remove tooltip from the range navigator?

Comment: Hi @hakkim, Sure, you can make a condition to prevent adding points from the navigator: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/whr3028x/